# onCompleted not called when using ConnectableObservable and

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

Given this:

```
TestSubscriber subscriber = new TestSubscriber();

ConnectableObservable<Integer> observable = Observable.just(1,2,3,4,5).publish();

observable.startWith(observable).subscribe(subscriber);

observable.connect();
```

The subscriber receives 1,2,3,4,5 in the onNext but does not receive onCompleted.

If I change the code to:

```
Observable.just(1,2,3,4,5).replay()
```

then the subscriber receives 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5 in the onNext and then onCompleted as well which is what I expect.

To me it should behave the same in both scenarios since all the subscriptions occur before calling .connect() in the first example.

Can someone please clarify why the first scenario behaves differently ?

Comment: In this particular case, the `publish()` disconnects after the first round and you waits for you to connect again for the second.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is related to this -- `observable.startWith(observable)`.  It is telling the observable emit all its items before it starts emitting all its items.

Try removing that part --

```
TestSubscriber subscriber = new TestSubscriber();

ConnectableObservable<Integer> observable = Observable.just(1,2,3,4,5).publish();
observable.subscribe(subscriber);
observable.connect();
```